# Is the video game played by Roland Schitt in S4E4 of Schitt's Creek real?

Tags: props, schitts-creek

In S04E04, Girl's Night, of *Schitt's Creek*, Roland Schitt plays a video game.

If it is a real one, what's the name of this game?

If it's not a real video game, it looks like a lot of effort was spent on that visual.

[image: Picture of game pause screen with character "elf lvl 98"; middle says "Area 1007 (The Kingdom)"]

Comment: If this gets closed as trivia (not sure whether it is or not), you could probably ask on [gaming.se] instead; as you have a screenshot of the game, it fits the criteria for identification questions.

Comment: Not sure if it's real, but don't be too quick to discount the amount of effort showrunners are willing to put into relatively small aspects of a show.  Consider all the *stuff* in a room that never gets referenced or used in any way, but sits there for the sole purpose of making the room look like someone lives there.